# Wrong CORS configuration in a SpringBoot project

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I'm developing a CRUD app that will serve REST in the SpringBoot part (it will have an Angular part too, consuming JSON). The SpringBoot part serves gracefully JSON (queries against a MySQL database) but when I run the part that tries to delete a record I get a 405 error:

"There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405)."

This is the code that fails (it's calling a @Service)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/avisos/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE) 
public ResponseEntity<Void> borraAviso(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
   
    boolean isRemoved;
    isRemoved = avisoService.borraAviso(id);

    if (!isRemoved) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        
}
```

This is the CORS configuration file:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
 
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                //.allowedMethods("GET", "POST");
                .allowedMethods("");
    }
}
```

The program runs in a Linux Mint box but I have tested that in a W8 box too and I get the same error.
(I'm using Spring Tool Suite 4, Version: 4.8.0.RELEASE, and Maven).

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the method has one issue

> @RequestMapping(value = "/avisos/delete/{id}", method =
> RequestMethod.DELETE)  public ResponseEntity
> borraAviso(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {

Here the `id` is a `PathVariable`. So the correct declaration would be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/avisos/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> borraAviso(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
```

By default, `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST` method are allowed for CORS if not overridden.

If you want to allow `DELETE` method, then the following config should work.

```
registry.addMapping("/**")
    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
    .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(),
         HttpMethod.HEAD.name(),
         HttpMethod.POST.name(),
         HttpMethod.DELETE.name()
    );
```

Comment: Hi, GSSwain: After that I get the same ".... .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]"

Comment: Can you create a sample project and share the github url here?